# Replace string pattern but keep part of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long document with some headings I want to replace in a operation.

The headings have the following structure (there are two nouns, both in with a uppercase first character, separated with a whitespace, also the time is dynamic):

```
let string = 'Firstname Lastname [00:01:02]';
```

I want to insert some characters at the front and the end of this string, but want to keep the content.

So the desired output should be something like:

```
let string = '{Firstname Lastname [00:01:02]}:';
```

I tried a little bit around with RegEx and can catch the time with the following pattern:

```
\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: Would be good to show us what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using captures in my RegEx.

```
/(\b[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z])?\b\s\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\])/g
```

This RegEx captures the pattern of my headings into group one. In a replace operation I can then insert the desired content.

```
string.replace(regex, '{$1}:')
```

Comment: you answered to your own question with the logic to extract the heading from a longer text but you accepted the answer that didn't and just gave for granted you had the string itself ready to be processed?

Comment: I don't get what you mean though. I did a mistake in accepting the other answer, but now changed it.